# Django - Comment form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have 4 models: User, Blogger, Post and Comment.

Now, in 'post_desc.html', i want to insert a comment box.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="comment" style="width: 800px; height: 145px;"></br></br>
    <button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
  </form>
{% else %}
  <p><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a> to comment</p>
{% endif %}
```

So, this form will only take comment from the user.

But how to store information like 'commented_by' which will the user that is currently logged in and 'commented_on' which will be the post_topic in which he/she is commenting.

How to store these information automatically? in views.py i tried 'request.user' but that didn't worked. Any solutions?

Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments')
    commented_on = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    commented_text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    commented_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField()
```

I did this in my view.py

```
def post_desc(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = request.POST['comment']
        comments = Comment.objects.create(
            commented_text = comment,
            commented_on = request.topic,
            commented_by = request.user
            )
        return redirect('post_desc', pk=post.pk)

    return render(request, 'post_desc.html', {'post': post})
```

But it is giving error, "'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'post'".

Comment: i can help only if you updated the question to include the comment model : )

Comment: We don't need the model as much as the view.

Comment: @mohammedqudah Updated.

Comment: @DanielRoseman View also update.

Comment: You need to also give the actual error. There's no reference to `request.post` in that code, so it wouldn't give you that error; it might give you an error for `request.topic` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your code is that there's no such thing as `request.topic`. The topic is the Post, which you already have.

```
    comments = Comment.objects.create(
        commented_text = comment,
        commented_on = post,
        commented_by = request.user
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to a  create a url that have a pk parameter to know where to post the comment *in which post?*:

```
url(r'add/comment/post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', views.new_comment, name="comment")
```

now let's create the view `new_comment`:

```
from django.utils import timezone
def new_comment(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    comment_text = request.POST['your-comment-input-name']
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    Comment.objects.create(created_by=user, text=comment_text, post=post, create_at=timezone.localtime(timezone.now()))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

> don't forget to set your form action to `action="{% url 'comment' Post.id %}"`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the original comment model. Why should it be changed?

Comment: i posted this answer before you update so sorry dont downvote

Comment: tell me if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have something like that in my blog project which I develop for improve myself in django python.

my model;

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey('post.Post', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Your Name')
comment = models.TextField(verbose_name='Your Comment')
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my view for post detail page;

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    comment = form.save(commit=False)
    comment.post = post
    comment.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('your redirect page')

context = {
    'post': post,
    'form': form,

}
return render(request, 'post/detail.html', context)
```

my post detail template page;

```
<h3>Comments;</h3>
        {% if post.comments.count <= 0 %}
            <h4>No comment yet!</h4>
        {% else %}
            {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                <h4>{{ comment.name }} |
                    <small>{{ comment.created_date|timesince }}</small>
                </h4>
                <p>{{ comment.comment|linebreaks }}</p>
                <hr/>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        <h3>Add Comment:</h3>
        {% include 'post/comment.html' %}
```

my comment form template;

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add Comment"/>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But in your views, you are not storing information like comment_time and user. Any reasons?

Comment: why not see my answer

Comment: @DeepakRawat as I said before I am just trying to deal with different technique for educational purpose. I am storing these on html page.